# Compile Play templates on save

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, scala-ide

How can I tell Play to compile templates immediately after saving the template file? This would be useful to pick up changes of template constructor without leaving Eclipse to hit refresh in the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the `~run` or `~compile` command:

In your shell

```
$ play
```

In the play console

```
~run
```

or directly in the shell

```
$ play ~run
```

Comment: Thanks. Life can be so easy! For other readers: [Play SBT documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/PlayConsole)

Comment: @biesior Thanks, I thought that it didn't work directly, but you're right !

Comment: @JulienLafont NP :) There is some mismatch when you want to use additional settings (i.e. non default port) - but it can be solved as well with proper use of quotas.